# How to use mysql find in set on list value selection

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where I want to select all record that user has not subscribed to. I tried using `FIND_IN_SET, NOT FIND_IN_SET`, but it doesn't work. Please how do i run this selection?

package

```
name    | id | subscribers 
--------|----|--------------------------------------
 PHP    | 1  | peter, john, hana, joe 
 Java   | 2  | mike, peter 
 Python | 3  | mike
 HTML   | 4  |
 CSS    | 5  |
```

Query

```
SELECT p.name
  FROM package p
WHERE FIND_IN_SET("peter", p.subscribers) = 0
/*NOT FIND_IN_SET("peter", p.subscribers)*/
LIMIT 10
```

Expected result

> Python HTML CSS

Comment: Remove the spaces after the commas in the column `subscribers`.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try tweaking query like below--

```
SELECT top 10 p.name
  FROM package p
WHERE p.subscribers NOT LIKE '%peter%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following query

```
SELECT package.name 
FROM package 
WHERE package.subscribers NOT LIKE '%john%';
```

`NOT LIKE '%john%'` checks that `john` is nowhere in the `subscribers` column

The result is as follows

```
Python 
HTML 
CSS
```

You can use `LIMIT 10` at the end of the query if you want to limit the number of results or use `TOP 10` near `SELECT` as mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have a *horrible* data model.  You should not be storing lists of names in a single string column. Instead, you should have a separate table with one row per package and subscriber.  That is the right way.

If you are given a really bad data model and you *cannot* fix it, you can do what you want.  I suspect that your particular problem are the spaces in the list.  So, to fix that remove them:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('peter', REPLACE(p.subscribers, ' ', '')) = 0
```

An alternative is to use `LIKE`:

```
WHERE CONCAT(', ', p.subscribers, ', ') LIKE CONCAT('%, ', 'peter', ', %')
```

However, your efforts should be going to fixing the data model rather than trying to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query :

```
SELECT name 
FROM package 
WHERE subscribers NOT LIKE '%peter%';
```